# Batch file to move second line/row of a csv/text file to another csv/text file (must skip first line of csv/text file)

Tags: csv, batch-file, text, move

I need to move second line of a csv/text file to another text/csv file.

I have a solution to delete the second line of csv/text file.

The first line of csv/text file contains header and must be not moved or deleted.

Warning: Path folders have spaces

My code

```
@echo off
Pushd "D:\Program Files\datasources\"

setlocal disableDelayedexpansion

>archive.new (
  break | for /F "tokens=*" %%F in (archive.csv) do @(
            echo %%F
            exit /b
          )
  for /F "skip=2 tokens=*" %%F in (archive.csv) do echo %%F
)

DEL /S "archive.csv"
REN "archive.new" "archive.csv"
```

I need only to move the second line in another file, this code delete the second line of text/csv file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are over complicating your code. Every line gets preserved in one file or another, so you might as well read every line in your one loop and then choose which file to write the line to based on the line number.

I use `SET /A` to increment a `ln` counter, and if the resultant value is 2 then I get a division by 0 error. The `&&` code writes all the success lines (all but 2) to the new archive, and the `||` code writes the failure (line 2) to the other file.

```
@echo off
pushd "d:\Program Files\datasources\"
set "src=archive.csv"
set "file2=otherFile.csv"
set ln=0
>"%src%.new" (
  for /f usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ("%src%") do (
    2>nul set /a "1/(2-(ln+=1))" && (echo(%%A) || (>>"%file2%" echo(%%A)
  )
)
move /y "%src%.new" "%src%" >nul
```

Some additional advanced "tricks" I employed:

- Use `usebackq` so file name can be enclosed in quotes, just in case there are spaces and or poison characters in the name.
- Use `move` instead of `del` followed by `ren`
- Arcane syntax to set both `eol` and `delims` to nothing, thus guaranteeing all lines are preserved exactly (provided they don't exceed the ~8191 character limit)
- Use `echo(` to guarantee correct output, no matter the line (including empty line)
- Put redirection in front and enclose `echo` statements in parentheses to ensure no unwanted trailing white space characters in output

Comment: Hi thanks for your replay, the  ~8191 character limit is total characters in files ? becase my file have 1000 line with more character and my code works.

Comment: @pachiro - No, I'm referring to the cmd.exe limit of 8191 characters per line.